# What is the fastest way to check if a string is present in a string array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I want to be able to check if the string `std::string x` is equal to any value in string array `std::string y[N]`. I know how to do this by using a `for` loop and using an `if` statement, but is there an even faster way that I could do this? Is there a built in function in c++ that can do this?

Comment: You should not use a string array in C++. Use a STL string.

Comment: Your wording is a little ambiguous. Is the type of `y` equal to `std::string` or `std::string[]`?

Comment: @パスカル what is that?

Comment: you can use `std::find`

Comment: There is `std::find` but that just hides the loop and comparison. You could use a `std::set` or `std::unodered_set` for faster lookups but that requires changing your data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you use STL classes, there's a few mechanisms you can use, depending on the domain of your problem.

For example, if the array is unsorted, then it doesn't really matter: there are StdLib algorithms which will better convey intent and shrink the code, but they'll be performance-wise equivalent to a simple for-loop. This code is identical, performance-wise, to a simple for-loop.

```
std::vector<std::string> strings = /*...*/;
//This will find the first string that matches the provided value and return its iterator
auto found_string_iterator = std::find(strings.begin(), strings.end(), "Desired String");
if(found_string_iterator != strings.end()) //found it
    std::cout << *found_string_iterator << std::endl;
else //Did not find it
    std::cout << "No such string found." << std::endl;
```

If the collection is sorted, you can use a Binary Search, which dramatically improves performance:

```
std::vector<std::string> sorted_strings = /*...*/;
//In a sorted collection, this returns iterators to all strings matching the provided value
auto string_range_iterators = std::equal_range(strings.begin(), strings.end(), "Desired String");
if(string_range_iterators.first != strings.end()) {
    for ( auto i = string_range_iterators.first; i != string_range_iterators.second; ++i )
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "No Strings found." << std::endl;
```

If you don't need duplicate strings in your collection, you can use a `set` or `unordered_set` to collect the strings, which will guarantee at least the performance of a binary-search, and if you use `unordered_set` instead, could be faster.

```
std::set<std::string> collected_strings = /*...*/;
auto found_string_iterator = collected_strings.find("Desired String");
if(found_string_iterator != strings.end()) //found it
    std::cout << *found_string_iterator << std::endl;
else //Did not find it
    std::cout << "No such string found." << std::endl;
```

Comment: Don't confuse runtime complexity with runtime performance.  It is not true, in general, that binary search "dramatically improves" performance.  In many common cases, a linear search will perform better.  Similarly, STL containers like set and unordered_set are quite expensive to build.  Use with care.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in container for that is `std::unordered_set<std::string>`

Replace your string array with that `unordered_set`, and the checks will become much faster:

```
bool contains( const std::unordered_set<std::string>& set, const std::string& s )
{
    return set.find( s ) != set.end();
}
```

Comment: `std::set` and `std::unordered_set` require that there be no duplicate strings in the collection. The OP hasn't specified that that's a constraint they can obey.

Comment: I don't understand, do I take away the string array or do I keep it and replace the "std::string" with that array name?

Comment: Why not just `set.count(s)`?  (which is already essentially the function you just wrote)

Comment: @HWalters In my STL, count calls equal_range then distance. find is slightly faster, it only calls lower_bound.

Comment: @Soonts First, number of functions isn't how you measure speed (if OP is really concerned about that, he should do more than count functions).  Second, you're comparing apples to oranges.  Even granting that `count()` _were_ slower, it's irrelevant, because `count()` _gives_ you the answer which is more or less directly useful.  `find()` only gives you some iterator, which doesn't tell you if it's in the container or not.  That's why you need to also call `end()`, which gives you _another_ iterator, to compare to.

Comment: @HWalters Fine, let’s compare apples to apples. In 64-bit release config on my pc, count() version takes 287-297ms, find + end version take 198-203ms: https://gist.github.com/Const-me/4f049a1edca85e677bfd1a56ba36117a As you see, regardless on your opinion about how I shouldn’t compare, my version is almost 50% faster in practice. Not a small difference.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "regardless on[sic] your opinion about how I shouldn't compare".  The apples to apples measurement of x against y on a particular implementation is actually a valid way to back a claim that x is faster than y.  This in no way suggests that comparing apples to oranges by counting function works.

Comment: @HWalters I didn’t just counted functions, I know how these particular functions work. lower_bound is simple, computes a hash and finds a node. equal_range returns a pair of begin + end iterators, so for the begin it computes same lower_bound, but it also computes the end iterator. And than there’s distance.
That’s how I was able to tell find()+end() will be faster than count(). You didn’t believe me, so I’ve made a benchmark that showed that indeed, count() is 50% slower.
For most people who code C++ speed is _very_ relevant, otherwise they’d choose a higher-level language instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155370/discussion-between-h-walters-and-soonts).